# Retriving all selected items of a dropdown in PHP using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form where I need to select multiple items from a single dropdown and use them in a query.
I have used the  tag for the dropdown and used the 'multiple' attribute to allow multiple selection.
I want to get all the selected items/indexes in a variable/array so that I can use it in tha query.
I tried using document.getElementById('statusselect').selectedindex but I get only 1 and not all.
I even tried using $('#statusselect option:selected') in jquery but in vain.

Please help me out with this!!
Thank You.
This the code for the dropdown where the values are fetched from database.
I want to get all the selected values in a variable on a button click.

```
    echo "<td>Status<br>";
    echo "<select multiple name=\"status\" size=5 id=\"statusselect\">";
    foreach($status_all as $status)
     {
      if (isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == $status)
       {
        echo "<option value=\"$status\" selected>".status_in_words($status)."</option>";
       }
      else
       {
        echo "<option value=\"$status\" >".status_in_words($status)."</option>";
       }
      }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td>";
```

Comment: could u post few codes otherwise its though to answer

Comment: It's a little confusing, are you trying to get the selected elements using Javascript or PHP after the form is submitted?

Comment: @Sajan Parikh : Its a PHP form. On the click of a button, I want to get all the selected values of the dropdown. Hope I am clear. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `:selected` on multiple select must use [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate through all the elements. As http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/ suggested, use this:

```
<select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Flowers</option>
    <option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
    <option>Trees</option>
    <option selected="selected">Bushes</option>
    <option>Grass</option>
    <option>Dirt</option>
</select>

<script>
$("select option:selected").each(function () {
    // your code
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!! Solved my issue within minutes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample HTML:

```
<select id="multiselect" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Using jQuery:

```
$("#multiselect").val()
```

Yields an array with selected values